# Custom UITableViewCell with Storyboard - no data display

Tags: sqlite, uitableview, storyboard

I read this tutorial

[ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/)
to implement a custom UITableViewCell.

In classic view the data are correctly display and I change this part of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    ItemObject *obj=[[restArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];


    UILabel *objNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    objNameLabel.text =obj.rag_soc;

    UILabel *objDetailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    objDetailLabel.text=obj.via;

    UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 44, 44)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"web_new.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
    [imv release];

    NSLog(@"%d",obj.nArrayIndex);
    [obj release];



    return cell;
}
```

When I run the code I don't see any data.

Comment: Did you do all the steps in interface builder like create the labels and imageView and give them the appropriate tags, otherwise your code won't reference anything

Answer (score 1):

Did you connect the tableview with the file Owner. Make sure both the data source and delegate is hooked to the file owner.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the cell identifier in story board (inspector -> identifier) and in code (CellIdentifier) match.